# pysimpleGui - Failed running script with pyinstaller --noconsole

Tags: windows, user-interface, console, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

I've my app written with **pysimplegui**, It runs well in windows when either if I run it directly in terminal `python3.5 myapp.py` or compile with `pyinstaller --onefile myapp.py`

however it fails, a window *pop-up window* shows with message:

> Fatal error detected. Failed to execute myapp

It often happens when I open a file in a remote location (mapped drive), but strangely it works in some remote sub-directories.

Where might the problem be? Since It occurs when I've compiled with `--noconsole` I don't really see the error (if any is returned)..

Comment: How about compiling leaving the console enabled so you can see if additional info is provided?